# Failed prop type: The prop `experience` is marked as required in `Experience`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am following the tutorial but i couldn't find the solution to my problem

**this is the my dashboard component**

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profile";

import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import DashboardActions from "./DashboardActions";
import Experience from "./Experience";

const Dashboard = ({
  getCurrentProfile,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
  }, []);

  return loading && profile === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
      <p className="lead">
        <i className="fas fa-user"> </i> Welcome {user && user.name}
      </p>

      {profile !== null ? (
        <Fragment>
          <DashboardActions />
          <Experience experience={profile.experience} />
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <p>You have not yet setup profile, please add some info</p>
          <Link to="/create-profile" className="btn btn-primary my-1">
            Create Profile
          </Link>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  profile: state.profile,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentProfile })(Dashboard);
```

**this my experiance component**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteExperience } from "../../actions/profile";

const Experience = ({ experience, deleteExperience }) => {
  const experiences = experience.map((exp) => (
    <tr key={exp._id}>
      <td>{exp.company}</td>
      <td className="hide-sm">{exp.title}</td>
      <td>
        <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.from}</Moment>-
        {exp.to === null ? (
          " Now"
        ) : (
          <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD">{exp.to}</Moment>
        )}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            deleteExperience("6219ee8ce87af3a86a11e783");
          }}
          className="btn btn-danger"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2 className="my-2">Experience Credentials</h2>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Title</th>
            <th className="hide-sm">Years</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{experiences}</tbody>
      </table>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Experience.propTypes = {
  experience: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  deleteExperience: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { deleteExperience })(Experience);
```

**delete experience function**

```
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(`/api/profile/experience/${id} `);

    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_PROFILE, payload: res.data });

    dispatch(setAlert("Experience Removed", "success"));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: err.response.statusText,
        status: err.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

***Given errors on browser***

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4061 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `experience` is marked as required in `Experience`, but its value is `undefined`.
    at Experience (http://localhost:3000/main.89309e0a5f8664ecdb15.hot-update.js:35:5)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48981:68)
    at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/main.6a1366a33ad002363333.hot-update.js:45:5)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48981:68)
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52195:29)
    at PrivateRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:4107:16)
    at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48981:68)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52397:29)
    at section
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51826:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51448:35)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48693:20)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69:51)
```

[end product is like this i could not delete the experience and printing the errors above besides if i try to remove experience it could remove in the backend but couldnt render in the front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9AWe.jpg)

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but when using functional components, you should use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks instead of the legacy `connect` and `mapStateToProps` API.

Comment: i have already used `mapStateToProp` and `connect` in other components it is as it should be but when I try to use it in delete function it is giving me error as above **@guillaume-brunerie**